# Sum of rows in SQL with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having a table with data like:

```
ID  OrderId TAX%    Quantity UnitCost
1     5      28    2       1280
2     5      18    1       1180
```

I want the output like:

```
ORDERID    TaxableValue       TaxValue
   5           3000               740
```

How can I achieve this? I tried with:

```
SELECT orderid,
       ROUND((SUM(UnitCost*Quantity)*TAX)/(100+TAX),2) AS taxValue,
       ROUND(SUM(unitCost*quantity)-ROUND((SUM(UnitCost*Quantity)*TAX)/(100+TAX),2),2) AS taxableValue 
FROM table1 
GROUP BY OrderId;
```

But the query above is not working.

Sorry all, That is the Tax percentage. This is the new Updated Query. Please consider this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i am getting data like Order Id -> 5, tax Value->81.81, taxable value->292.19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select OrderId
    , SUM((unitcost * quantity * tax)/(100+tax)) as TaxValue
    , SUM(unitcost * quantity)-SUM((unitcost * quantity * tax)/(100+tax)) as taxableValue
from table1
group by OrderId
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure it is as simple as doing a little math.

```
select OrderID
    , TaxableValue = SUM(UnitCost - TAX)
    , TaxValue = SUM(TAX * Quantity)
from YourTable
group by OrderID
```

EDIT: The math was slightly off on the `TaxableValue`

For those who want proof that this works.

```
declare @Something table
(
    ID int
    , OrderId int
    , TAX int
    , Quantity int
    , UnitCost int
)

insert @Something values
(1, 5, 28, 2, 228)
, (2, 5, 18, 1, 118)

select OrderID
    , TaxableValue = SUM(UnitCost - TAX)
    , TaxValue = SUM(TAX * Quantity)
from @Something
group by OrderID
```

Comment: You bet brother.

Comment: I'm doubt about your output with OP's expected result

Comment: @SeanLange It's nice, you got it

Comment: @SaiRam can you explain what is wrong? It returns EXACTLY what you stated you want.

Comment: @SeanLange - You had this query before you corrected it `select OrderID
    , TaxableValue = SUM(UnitCost) - SUM(TAX * Quantity)
    , TaxValue = SUM(TAX * Quantity)
from Table1
group by OrderID` and it had wrong output, but the current one is correct now !

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir and that is why it was corrected long before the comment about it being wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange - I am just clarifying things, if you look @SaiRam's comment, he wrote `query result was wrong.` and i also said that it was wrong before, not now!

Comment: SELECT orderid,
       ROUND((SUM(unitcost*quantity)*tax)/(100+tax),2) AS taxValue,
       ROUND(SUM(unitcost*quantity)-ROUND((SUM(unitcost*quantity)*tax)/(100+tax),2),2) AS taxableValue 
FROM orders 
GROUP BY OrderId,tax;
this query is working but returning the two rows. i want the result based on orderid only.

Comment: Why are you grouping by tax then?

Comment: @SeanLange, after running your query returning result like 
orderid     taxvalue    TaxableValue
5                 81.81       292.19

Comment: @SaiRam again....the query posted in this answer is EXACTLY what you stated you want as output. If it is not correct then you need to update your question and explain what you want.

Comment: @SeanLange, I haven't add any new columns in query. i need just that 3 only.

Comment: You have unitcostquantity, is that supposed to be unitcost * quantity? And that is completely different than what I posted. I can't help you when a solution that works you say is not correct but can't explain what is wrong.

Comment: @SeanLange, I posted the result of your query also. but actually that is not the expected output. I have posted in my question, what result i need.

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Post it as an answer and you will be able to mark it as an answer too.

Comment: @SeanLange, Sorry,  have posted the Table structure wrongly, in table tax means tax percentage, Not tax Amount. Need to calculate the tax amount based on the percentage. helpme out on this.

Comment: Then can you update your desired output based on this?

Comment: @SeanLange, I have updated the Table and expected output.

Comment: @SeanLange, i am expecting this should work. Please confirm.
select OrderId
    , SUM((unitcost*quantity * tax)/(100+tax)) as TaxValue
    , SUM(unitcost * quantity)-SUM((unitcost*quantity * tax)/(100+tax)) as taxableValue
from table1
group by OrderId

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done.

```
SELECT 
orderid, 
sum(unitcost*quantity) - sum(tax*quantity) as taxablevalue,
sum(tax*quantity) as taxvalue
FROM table1  
GROUP BY OrderId;
```